# onclick javascript in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form that asks for a password. If the correct password is entered, then another form will show. If not, an alert box will appear then reload the page. Now I have made a `php` so that no one can see the password. The situation now is, the second form that I did, is hidden, so what I did is to put a `javascript function()` in the button that hides and shows the form. Then I `echo` it in php. The problem now is, whenever I click on the submit button, the form still shows even if I didn't put a password. My question is, how can I successfully implement this code and run my program correctly?

**HTML**

```
<!-- *** password form *** -->
      <form id="frmPw" method="get" action="http://dashboard.site_practice.co/transfer/password_protect_transfer.php" style="float:left;">
       <label for="element_1">
        Enter password to view content.
       </label>
       <div>
        <input id="pw" name="password" type="password" placeholder="" style="width:200px;" required=""/>
       </div>
       <button id="submit" name="submit" style="width: 100px; float:left;">
        Submit
       </button>
      </form>

<!-- *** select form *** -->
    <form method="POST" id="frmSelect" style="display:none;" action="http://dashboard.site_practice.co/transfer/transfer.php">
      <label class="control-label" for="selectbasic-0">Select an account :</label><br>
        <select id="selectbasic-0" name="selectbasic-0" required="">
          <option value="1">ABC</option>
          <option value="2">DEF</option>
          <option value="3">GHI</option>
          <option value="4">JKL</option>
        </select>
    <br>
      <label class="control-label" for="name">Enter name:</label><br>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" required="" style="width:150px;">
    <br>
      <label class="control-label" for="submit"></label>
        <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Join!</button>
    </form>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
function pW() {
        document.getElementById('frmSelect').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('frmPw').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$pw = $_POST['password'];

if($pw == "admin1234"){
    echo pW();
}else{
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("Access Denied - Password Incorrect, Please Try Again");
</script>
<?php
 }
?>
```

Comment: you cannot call js functions from php code

Comment: Like @Lashane said, you can't do what you're doing. Instead, for the first if statement, echo something like "success". Read this with an if/else statement in your page's javascript and that's where you call the `pW` function.

Comment: So you know how to call one JavaScript function – `alert` – correctly “from within PHP”, but you are not able to transfer that knowledge to calling another JS function? And btw., you don’t need to use JavaScript for this in the first place – instead you could simply _not_ output the `style="display:none;"` attribute on the form, by checking whether or not a password was send right there and then in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

i tried your code. it's working when i change `$_POST['password']` to `$_GET['password']`. i hope it it will help.

```
 <?php

    $pw = $_GET['password']; //change $_POST to $_GET
    if($pw == "admin1234"){
    echo pW();
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///if password is correct, here will be your code for next step////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }else{

 ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("Access Denied - Password Incorrect, Please Try Again");
</script>

<?php
   }
?>
```